# dyanamic php and bootstrap carousel is not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have this code that does not make the carousel but instead puts all the images on top of each other and the image sliding does not work.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `posts`");

    $extensions_arr = array("svg", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      if(in_array($row['postFileType'], $extensions_arr)) {
   ?>
     <div class="item">
       <img src="<?php echo $row['post']; ?>" style="height: 25vh;" />
     </div>
  <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
  </div>
  <a href="#mycarousel" class="left carousel-control" dataslide="prev" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left prevSlide"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#mycarousel" class="right carousel-control" dataslide="next" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right nextSlide"></i>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Update code:

```
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                              <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <?php
                                $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `posts`");

                                $extensions_arr = array("svg", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

                                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                                    if(in_array($row['postFileType'], $extensions_arr)) {
                                      ?>
                                      <div class="carousel-item">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $row['post']; ?>" style="height: 25vh;" />
                                      </div>
                                      <?php
                                    }
                                  }
                              ?>
                              </div>
                              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
                              </div>
```

also the classes that were changed are these:
I changed dataride to data-ride changed item to carousel-item changed dataslide into data-slide but it still does not work

Comment: `dataride` should be `data-ride`. `item` should be `carousel-item`. `dataslide` should be `data-slide`. Better go read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/) What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: In your "_updated code_" ... `dataride` is still wrong

Comment: No clue. Do you know how to debug/use your browsers devtools? Any error in your console? Does the example from [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#example) even work?

Comment: @kerbh0lz the below answer by dutchboii worked the main thing here is that i was using bootstrap 3 classes instead of 4 and i wasn't using active class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the classes for a Bootstrap 3.* carousel As you said in the comments you have Bootstrap 4. The carousel structure is changed since Bootstrap 4. Try to convert your code to the new Bootstrap carousel structure.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/

Edit:

You forgot to make an item active I've changed your code. (not tested)

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `posts`");

        $extensions_arr = array("svg", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

        $index = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            if (in_array($row['postFileType'], $extensions_arr)) {
        ?>
                <div class="carousel-item <?= ($index === 0 ? 'active' : '') ?>">
                    <img src="<?= $row['post']; ?>" style="height: 25vh;" />
                </div>
        <?php
            }
            $index++;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `dataride` ... should be `data-ride`

Comment: Awesome to hear

Comment: @DutchBoii Just forgot to tell you please delete your old comments like I did as StackOverflow comments is not for long discussions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!